# XAMPP upgrade MARIADB 10.1 to 10.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp, mariadb

I use XAMPP v7.3 on my linux computer. This XAMPP version implement MariaDB 10.1.37 but I need the last version : 10.3.

I tried to install it separately with this [tuto](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04/). The installation was a success but phpmyadmin was unable to make the connection (access denied). Indeed the old MariaDB 10.1 was still here...

I need yours help. How I can replace the current version of MariaDB 10.1 of XAMPP by the latest version (10.3) ? I Googled-it without success...

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem,

I edit `xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini` using a text editor like Notepad

Find `skip-federated`, `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2`, and add a # in front (to the left) of it to comment out the lines if it exists (like `#skip-federated`).

After that I start the console and run `mysql_upgrade`.

You can use the console for watching other errors